# split linked list into smaller lists better than o(n) complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

```
list split(int size,list l){

...........
}
```

needed to write a routine, so that it can divide the original linked-list into multiple smaller linked-list of size (provided as a function argument).

is it possible to do this better than o(n) complexity. as linked-list is not indexed data structure. can we take benefit of multiple threads

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no use in using threads, since the `O(n)` is caused by searching the position, not the actual splitting, which can be done in `O(1)`. So even if you used threads (no idea how you'd want to achieve this though), you'd wind up with `O(n)`, since each thread has to search the node at which it splits the list.

Answer (score 0):

To work with linked list you must have to visit all the nodes then only you can make other lists. I don't think this can be done in O(n).

Comment: You probably mean in less than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the data structure and the algorithm on hand, using a constant number of threads never lowers the asymptotic complexity. `O(n)` remains `O(n)`.

To truly lower it, you would need a variable number of threads, which is mainly of theoretical interest, and not possible in practice as the number of cores is fixed.

(Not counting the fact that linked list traversal cannot be parallelized at all.)

---

If the list is bidirectional and its size is known in advance, you can let two threads perform the splits from both ends in parallel and process half of the elements each. In the end, the two partial sublists formed in the middle will have to be joined. The is a little complication as one of the sublists can be shorter than the size.

This will provide a maximum speedup of `2` (in theory) and does not generalize to more threads.

If the number of elements isn't known in advance, you need to synchronize the threads so that they don't cross, probably with a catastrophic performance degradation.

---

If you insist having more parallelism, that you can consider an enhanced linked list structure with `p` extra pointers to intermediate nodes. This will allow `p` threads to start working on `p` sections of the list simultaneously.

Anyway, for any change to a list (such a splitting in sublists!), you will have to keep the positions of these pointers updated. A paranoid approach.